# MySqlBulkLoader using a DataTable instead of a file

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I'm providing *MySql* compatibility for my program that previously worked only with SQL Server. I used `SqlBulkCopy` and I would like to use it with MySql as well. I know there is [MySqlBulkLoader](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html) that can be used to perform the same task. The difference however is that `SqlBulkCopy` worked with a `DataTable` so I prepared my `DataTable` and then performed the copy. `MySqlBulkLoader`, as far as I know, is used to copy an entire file into the database. But I am not dealing with a file here and I would prefer to skip extra steps of converting my `DataTable` into a temp file, performing the BulkCopy and then deleting the temp file.

Is there a way to make `MySqlBulkLoader` work with `DataTable`s? Is there a trustworthy alternative to `MySqlBulkLoader`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using the MySql Connector/NET, but which version of it?

Assuming that you're using the latest version (8.0 at current time), a look at the [MySQL Connector/NET 8.0 API Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlBulkLoader.htm) shows that there is no other option than importing your data from an existing file.

Seems like your proposed method is the only workaround for that...